# Is it possible to renumber the cases in different claims?

Tags: labels, cases

In my theorem, there are several claims, such as Claim 1 and Claim 2. They each have one or more cases. However, the case numbering does not take into account the occurrence of claims and is labeled as 1, 2, 3, 4 ... . I would like to renumber the cases in each new claim, starting from 1.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
   
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}

\begin{claim}
...
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}

\begin{case}
...
\end{case}

\begin{case}
...
\end{case}
\end{proof}
\begin{claim}
...
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
\begin{case}
...
\end{case}

\begin{case}
...
\end{case}
\end{proof}      
\end{proof}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can (and should) use the optional third argument [within], such as `\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[theorem]` and `\newtheorem{case}{Case}[claim]`.  If you can have cases without claims, you can add `\counterwithin{case}{theorem}` (if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the case-counter by adding the line `\setcounter{case}{0}`. Since with every new case the counter is incremented by 1, you should set it to 0 before opening the case you want to give the number 1.

Your code would then look like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
   
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}

\begin{claim}
...
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}

\begin{case}
...
\end{case}

\begin{case}
...
\end{case}
\end{proof}
\begin{claim}
...
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
\setcounter{case}{0}
\begin{case}
...
\end{case}

\begin{case}
...
\end{case}
\end{proof}      
\end{proof}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have a new enough TeX version, you can make this automatic with `\AddToHook{env/proof/begin}{\setcounter{case}{0}}`.

Comment: @Teepeemm DraUX's answer suits me well. I'm unsure which new version your command is supported in (for example, texlive 2021?).